# I found a story I wrote as a little kid. Should I finish it?

Tags: novel, book, horror

There was this story I was writing, when I was a little kid, that I found. I called it "Rage." I liked the story, and also liked a lot of the plot points. I want to continue it.

However, should I continue it, because a) I wrote it a while ago and b) I can't really remember that many plot points that I had been planning to write.

In fact, this one important part of the story, I completely forgot what the plot was going to lead into!

However, a) I still remember SOME parts and b) it's actually a very engaging story.

There's this one part that I changed my mind about, but it kind of leads me to nowhere if I do that. In the situation, I was planning for something horrible to happen to my character, but I've recently decided against it.

So should I continue my story?

Comment: Why not turn the Question round and try to find a reason not to finish it? If you could ask your younger self, what would that child say?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Sorry this is a little late, but I was busy...but thank you! That is a very good point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Found Gold**:

Of COURSE you should finish it! Is the young version of you going to do it? Is the young version of you going to come along and complain that you aren't getting it right? **NO**.

You wrote it, it's yours. If you like the story and plot, even better. You can do honor to your younger self by finishing it. So, you may not do it exactly like you would have. Obviously your younger self lost interest, drive, or inspiration to do it. Well, now you've found those things.

Even if you only write it for you, and for peace of mind, it's a good idea. Rewrite it (on the computer if the original was paper) and save the original if you want the original preserved.

Answer (score 4):

IF you like the premise, plot, and/or characters (and your post implies you do!) then by all means scoop up the pieces of that baby and do some brainstorming. Figure out which bits you like and want to use, which you don't like so much and might wanna scrap, whether or not there's anything you want to add, etc. Go for it! It can actually be really nice rediscovering an old story that has promise, because with a few years behind you and a different perspective to bring to bear you often think of new ways to make it even better!

...I'd just recommend a complete rewrite from the beginning, even if you aren't planning to alter a thing from the original plot or concept as best you recollect it. Unless you were one super talented youngster who then spent the next several years slacking and learning absolutely nothing new as a writer, I think you'll find your prose back in the day pales compared to what the older, wiser, more experienced author you can craft now!

Answer (score 3):

Ummm... Asking this question answers this question. ;P Obviously you enjoy what you're seeing and you can consider it as an "Inspiration" if nothing else. You can either just pick up where you left off and come back to tighten the beginning when you've finished your Rough Draft, OR you can just start from scratch and use that as your reference material as you craft the story anew. Whichever feels better to you.

I'd say that if you already *plan* on going back to "Edit" the beginning over and over as you continue the story that you just start it from the beginning so that you can iron these things out as you go along instead of constantly revisiting it.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you forget parts of the story, (in my experience) re-writing always makes it better.